# Rails form_for error when passing attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, form-for

I'm trying to add javascript validation to my form using Parsley.

Code:

```
<%= form_for(@spot), :html => {:"data-parsley-validate" => ''} do |f| %>
…
```

The error i'm receiving:

```
SyntaxError in SpotsController#new

/app/views/spots/_form.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting keyword_end ...end= form_for(@spot), :html => {:"data-parsley-validate" =>...
/app/views/spots/_form.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end ...ata-parsley-validate" => ''} do |f| @output_buffer.safe_appe…
/app/views/spots/_form.html.erb:54: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Form for is expecting the html key-value pair to be within its arguments

Either remove the parenthesis around @spot 
or

```
<%= form_for(@spot, html: {:"data-parsley-validate" => ''}) do |f| %>
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for